# Sort Datatable and Rank Using ratio

Tags: c#, sql, sorting, datacolumn

I have a query where i get some columns from database it is simple select statement then I add columns to this datatable as :

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ratio", typeof(double)));
```

Then I have another column called Rank which is again added manually as follow :

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Rank", typeof(int)));
```

now how do I first of all sort by ratio and then add rank using the ratio e.g. the higher the ratio the higher the rank for example if ratio is 3, 5 and 9 once ordered by ratio it should be :

```
rank ratio
1    9
2    5
3    3
```

**EDIT :**

the ratio is calculated by dividing the two columns in my query

```
 foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
 {
row["Ratio"] = (Convert.ToDecimal(row["LastMonth"]) / NoOfBranches).ToString("0.##");
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: If you tell us how you determine ratio, I can make you get that query directly from SQL Server (assuming that's your RDBMS), without having to add them in the C# code

Comment: can you get the ratio of every row using your data only or there is an application rule to get it?

Comment: @Adrian I calculate the ratio using two fields in my sql query - I will update the question

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I get the ratio on row based got for each loop on dt.rows and divide two of my query columns to get ratio

Comment: @Sam1 looks like you can generate the ratio inside your query, no need to add the column dynamically in runtime.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza no i cannot because i get those columns from manually added columns in foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this from the C# side of the world:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "ratio DESC";
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Rank", typeof(int)));
int count = 1;
foreach (DataRowView dr in dt.DefaultView)
{
    dr["Rank"] = count++;
}
```

Whenever using the DataTable, you need to refer to dt.DefaultView as it is the sorted version of the table.  See the MSDN for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview.aspx

Comment: Whenever you use the datatable for anything, you need to refer to it as: dt.DefaultView or it will be in the order that it was placed in the datatable in the first place.

Comment: cool that solved it you need to edit your code to foreach (DataRowView dr ..... thank you  :)

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help :)  Mark as answer if you see fit ;)

Answer (score 2):

Using the information <strike>and the restrinctions</strike> you have given us, I'll suggest the next code:

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Ratio", typeof(double)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Rank", typeof(int)));

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    row["Ratio"] =
        (Convert.ToDecimal(row["LastMonth"]) / NoOfBranches).ToString("0.##");
}
//sorting the DataTable using the new DataColumn
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Ratio DESC";
//after the sort, set the rank for each one
int rank = 1;
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    row["Rank"] = rank++;
}
```

Example extracted from [forum post](http://www.dotnetexpertsforum.com/how-to-sort-data-in-datatable-using-c-t806.html).

Comment: You'll need to switch the sort from ASC to DESC.  He wants high to low ratio.

Comment: @ImGreg answer edited, and added the code to set the rank column and values

Answer (score 1):

Direct from db:

```
SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ratio DESC) AS rank,ratio FROM [YourTableName]
```